# How to implement left join in JOIN Extension method

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I am trying to implement an outer join on this kind of query for the `p.Person` table.
How would I do this?

This example is taken from http://ashishware.com/DSLinqExample.shtml

```
var onlyinfo = p.Person
    .Where(n => n.FirstName.Contains('a'))
    .Join(p.PersonInfo,
        n => n.PersonId,
        m => m.PersonId,
        (n, m) => m)
    .ToArray<Persons.PersonInfoRow>();
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Normally left joins in LINQ are modelled with group joins, sometimes in conjunction with `DefaultIfEmpty` and `SelectMany`:

```
var leftJoin = p.Person.Where(n => n.FirstName.Contains("a"))
                       .GroupJoin(p.PersonInfo, 
                                  n => n.PersonId,
                                  m => m.PersonId,
                                  (n, ms) => new { n, ms = ms.DefaultIfEmpty() })
                       .SelectMany(z => z.ms.Select(m => new { n = z.n, m }));
```

That will give a sequence of pairs (n, m) where `n` is the entry from `p.Person` and `m` is the entry from `p.PersonInfo`, but `m` will be null if there are no matches.

(It's completely untested, btw - but should give you the idea anyway :)

Comment: first anonymous projection doesn't work - compiler says 'Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access'

Comment: With SQL profiler I am seeing two separate queries, one for each table. Does that mean the left join is performed in memory and not by SQL server? TIA.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ: I would *expect* it to all be done in SQL Server, but without being able to experiment myself, I wouldn't like to say for sure. (We don't have any kind of context for whether this is EF, Linq to SQL, something else etc.) I suggest you ask a new question.

Answer (score 17):

For Left outer Join try Following query. This is tested

```
var leftJoin = Table1
                .GroupJoin(
                               inner: Table2,
                    outerKeySelector: t1 => t1.Col1,
                    innerKeySelector: t2 => t2.Col2,
                      resultSelector: ( t1, t2Rows ) => new { t1, t2Rows.DefaultIfEmpty() }
                )
                .SelectMany( z =>
                    z.t2Rows.Select( t2 =>
                        new { t1 = z.t1, t2 = t2 }
                    )
                );
```

Answer (score 14):

If anyone comes across this question and wants an extension method to accomplish this, I created one using the same approach as the other answers. It has the same signature as the regular join extension method.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> LeftJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer,
    IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
    Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector,
    Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector,
    Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    return outer
        .GroupJoin(inner,
            outerKeySelector,
            innerKeySelector,
            (outerObj, inners) => new { outerObj, inners = inners.DefaultIfEmpty() })
        .SelectMany(a => a.inners.Select(innerObj => resultSelector(a.outerObj, innerObj)));
}
```

Comment: In my tests this does not emit SQL left join query, but does two separate queries independent of one another, and then does the left join _in memory_. But when I do the same thing in place (i.e. not using an extension method), it emits `left outer join` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following extension method on of my project, It might help you.

```
/// <summary>
/// Performs a left outer join on two collections.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TLeft">Type of left IEnumerable collection</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TRight">Type of left IEnumerable collection</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key returned by the key selector functions.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TResult">The type of the result elements.</typeparam>
/// <param name="left"> The left IEnumerable collection of the join operation.</param>
/// <param name="right"> The right IEnumerable collection of the join operation.</param>
/// <param name="leftKeySelector">Function that projects the key given an element from <paramref name="left"/>.</param>
/// <param name="rightKeySelector">Function that projects the key given an element from <paramref name="right"/>.</param>
/// <param name="resultSelector">Function that projects the result given 
///     an element from <paramref name="left"/> and 
///     an element from <paramref name="right"/>
///     that match on a common key.</param>
/// <returns>A sequence containing results projected from a left outer join of the two input collections.</returns>

public static IQueryable<TResult> LeftJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TLeft> left,
    IQueryable<TRight> right,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector)
{
    if (left == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(left));
    if (right == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(right));
    if (leftKeySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(leftKeySelector));
    if (rightKeySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rightKeySelector));
    if (resultSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resultSelector));

    return left
        .AsExpandable() // LinqKit to convert everything into an expression tree.
        .GroupJoin(
            right,
            leftKeySelector,
            rightKeySelector,
            (leftItem, rightItem) => new { leftItem, rightItem })
        .SelectMany(
            joinResult => joinResult.rightItem.DefaultIfEmpty(),
            (joinResult, rightItem) =>
                resultSelector.Invoke(joinResult.leftItem, rightItem));
}
```

And this is how it was called

```
base.context.Users
    .LeftJoin(
        base.context.Workers
        user => user.Userid,
        worker => worker.Workerid,
        (user, worker) => new
        {
            User = user,
            Worker = worker
        })
```

Got this answer here, [Trying to implement a LeftJoin extension method to work with EF Core 2.0](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/46537158/trying-to-implement-a-leftjoin-extension-method-to-work-with-ef-core-2-0)