# Trying to implement a LeftJoin extension method to work with EF Core 2.0

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I am trying to have an extension method to implement left outer join which returns `IQueryable` that run against EF Core 2.0 data context.

I read the Stack Overflow thread here for help: [Extension method for IQueryable left outer join using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615693/extension-method-for-iqueryable-left-outer-join-using-linq).  The accepted answer had some problems that were addressed in a later answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35414717/3914623) by Jan Van der Haegen.  I attempted to use the LeftJoin extension method described there with an EF Core 2.0 data context and ran into an exception which I cannot seem to resolve.

As I cannot find any fault with the implementation of the LeftJoin extension method, I attempted to run the same method against a data context using EF6 and it worked as expected. I have shared my experiment including the SQL scripts to generate the test data here:

[Experiment with LeftJoin extension run against EF6 and EF Core 2.0](https://github.com/hewasud/Experiment_20171002)

It contains two projects one running LeftJoin against EF6 and the other running it against EF Core 2.0.  The extension method is shared via a .Net Standard 2.0 class library.

The extension method for LeftJoin is as follows:

```
namespace QueryableExtensions
{
    // Much of the code copied from following URL:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615693/extension-method-for-iqueryable-left-outer-join-using-linq
    internal class KeyValuePairHolder<T1, T2>
    {
        public T1 Item1 { get; set; }
        public T2 Item2 { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ResultSelectorRewriter<TOuter, TInner, TResult> : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult>> resultSelector;
        public Expression<Func<KeyValuePairHolder<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>>, TInner, TResult>> CombinedExpression { get; private set; }

        private ParameterExpression OldTOuterParamExpression;
        private ParameterExpression OldTInnerParamExpression;
        private ParameterExpression NewTOuterParamExpression;
        private ParameterExpression NewTInnerParamExpression;

        public ResultSelectorRewriter(Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult>> resultSelector)
        {
            this.resultSelector = resultSelector;
            this.OldTOuterParamExpression = resultSelector.Parameters[0];
            this.OldTInnerParamExpression = resultSelector.Parameters[1];

            this.NewTOuterParamExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(KeyValuePairHolder<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>>));
            this.NewTInnerParamExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TInner));

            var newBody = this.Visit(this.resultSelector.Body);
            var combinedExpression = Expression.Lambda(newBody, new ParameterExpression[] { this.NewTOuterParamExpression, this.NewTInnerParamExpression });
            this.CombinedExpression = (Expression<Func<KeyValuePairHolder<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>>, TInner, TResult>>)combinedExpression;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            if (node == this.OldTInnerParamExpression)
                return this.NewTInnerParamExpression;
            else if (node == this.OldTOuterParamExpression)
                return Expression.PropertyOrField(this.NewTOuterParamExpression, "Item1");
            else
                throw new InvalidOperationException("What is this sorcery?", new InvalidOperationException("Did not expect a parameter: " + node));
        }
    }

    public static class JoinExtensions
    { 
        internal static readonly System.Reflection.MethodInfo
            Enumerable_DefaultIfEmpty = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
                .First(x => x.Name == "DefaultIfEmpty" && x.GetParameters().Length == 1);
        internal static readonly System.Reflection.MethodInfo
            Queryable_SelectMany = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
                .Where(x => x.Name == "SelectMany" && x.GetParameters().Length == 3)
                .OrderBy(x => x.ToString().Length).First();
        internal static readonly System.Reflection.MethodInfo
            Queryable_Where = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
                .First(x => x.Name == "Where" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2);
        internal static readonly System.Reflection.MethodInfo
            Queryable_GroupJoin = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
                .First(x => x.Name == "GroupJoin" && x.GetParameters().Length == 5);

        public static IQueryable<TResult> LeftJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
                   this IQueryable<TOuter> outer,
                   IQueryable<TInner> inner,
                   Expression<Func<TOuter, TKey>> outerKeySelector,
                   Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> innerKeySelector,
                   Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult>> resultSelector)
        {

            var keyValuePairHolderWithGroup = typeof(KeyValuePairHolder<,>)
                .MakeGenericType(
                    typeof(TOuter),
                    typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TInner))
                );
            var paramOuter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TOuter));
            var paramInner = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<TInner>));

            var resultSel = Expression
                .Lambda(
                    Expression.MemberInit(
                        Expression.New(keyValuePairHolderWithGroup),
                        Expression.Bind(
                            keyValuePairHolderWithGroup.GetMember("Item1").Single(),
                            paramOuter
                            ),
                        Expression.Bind(
                            keyValuePairHolderWithGroup.GetMember("Item2").Single(),
                            paramInner
                            )
                        ),
                    paramOuter,
                    paramInner
                );
            var groupJoin = Queryable_GroupJoin
                .MakeGenericMethod(
                    typeof(TOuter),
                    typeof(TInner),
                    typeof(TKey),
                    keyValuePairHolderWithGroup
                )
                .Invoke(
                    "ThisArgumentIsIgnoredForStaticMethods",
                    new object[]{
                        outer,
                        inner,
                        outerKeySelector,
                        innerKeySelector,
                        resultSel
                    }
                );


            var paramGroup = Expression.Parameter(keyValuePairHolderWithGroup);
            Expression collectionSelector = Expression.Lambda(
                            Expression.Call(
                                    null,
                                    Enumerable_DefaultIfEmpty.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TInner)),
                                    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(paramGroup, keyValuePairHolderWithGroup.GetProperty("Item2")))
                            ,
                            paramGroup
                        );

            Expression newResultSelector =
                new ResultSelectorRewriter<TOuter, TInner, TResult>(resultSelector)
                    .CombinedExpression;


            var selectMany1Result = Queryable_SelectMany
                .MakeGenericMethod(
                    keyValuePairHolderWithGroup,
                    typeof(TInner),
                    typeof(TResult)
                )
                .Invoke(
                    "ThisArgumentIsIgnoredForStaticMethods",
                    new object[]
                    {
                        groupJoin,
                        collectionSelector,
                        newResultSelector
                    }
                );
            return (IQueryable<TResult>)selectMany1Result;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above with a data context by EF Core 2.0 I get the following exception thrown at runtime:

```
System.ArgumentNullException occurred
  HResult = 0x80004003
  Message = Value cannot be null.
    Source =< Cannot evaluate the exception source>
      StackTrace:
   at Remotion.Utilities.ArgumentUtility.CheckNotNull[T](String argumentName, T actualValue)
   at Remotion.Utilities.ArgumentUtility.CheckNotNullOrEmpty(String argumentName, String actualValue)
   at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.GroupJoinClause..ctor(String itemName, Type itemType, JoinClause joinClause)
   at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.GroupJoinExpressionNode.ApplyNodeSpecificSemantics(QueryModel queryModel, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
   at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.MethodCallExpressionNodeBase.Apply(QueryModel queryModel, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
   at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.QueryParser.ApplyAllNodes(IExpressionNode node, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
   at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.QueryParser.ApplyAllNodes(IExpressionNode node, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
   at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.QueryParser.GetParsedQuery(Expression expressionTreeRoot)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](Expression query, INodeTypeProvider nodeTypeProvider, IDatabase database, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Type contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<> c__DisplayClass15_0`1.< Execute > b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at TestWithEFCore2.Program.Main() in C: \Users\hewasud\Git\TestLeftJoinExtensionWithEF6\TestWithEF6\TestWithEFCore2\Program.cs:line 27
```

My questions:

1. Is this a bug in EF Core 2.0 or am I doing something wrong here?
2. Is there a better way to produce an extension method which combines the GroupJoin and SelectMany methods to perform a LeftJoin when using EF Core 2.0 assuming that this code must be functional within a .Net Standard class library allowing portability?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the generated expression tree, write C# code to match, see what happens then. If it then works, find the difference between the two and work on getting that in the extension method. If it then still doesn't work, at least you have reduced the question to something simpler.

Comment: As there are three expressions that are passed in as parameters to LeftJoin extension and the modified resultSelector expression which is modified within by the expression visitor.  I am assuming that you want me to replace the modified resultSelector expression with C# code to test.  I am not sure if I can use straight C# effectively in place of the modified resultSel expression to make this method workable for any arbitrary case.  I may be able to gain some insight by replacing it with C# to test for a specific case.  I will  try this.

Comment: Dispute all efforts I was not able to get this LeftJoin working with Expressions to be used with EF Core and in .Net Core and .Net Standard projects.   The LinqKit library did provide a workable solution that is portable to .Net Core projects and usable in .Net Standard libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39890771/3914623), Only workable solution was using the **LinqKit.Core** library.  Despite all effort I was not able to get the Expression based solution to work with EF.Core under .Net Core or .Net Standard library projects.  **LinqKit.Core** library was the key to have the extension be portable and used within a .Net Standard 2.0 class library project.

As it was suggested, with LinkqKit.Core the solution is very simple:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Implement Left Outer join implemented by calling GroupJoin and
    /// SelectMany within this extension method
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TOuter">Outer Type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TInner">Inner Type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">Key Type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">Result Type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="outer">Outer set</param>
    /// <param name="inner">Inner set</param>
    /// <param name="outerKeySelector">Outer Key Selector</param>
    /// <param name="innerKeySelector">Inner Key Selector</param>
    /// <param name="resultSelector">Result Selector</param>
    /// <returns>IQueryable Result set</returns>
    public static IQueryable<TResult> LeftJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
       this IQueryable<TOuter> outer,
       IQueryable<TInner> inner,
       Expression<Func<TOuter, TKey>> outerKeySelector,
       Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> innerKeySelector,
       Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult>> resultSelector)
    {
        //LinqKit allows easy runtime evaluation of inline invoked expressions
        // without manually writing expression trees.
        return outer
            .AsExpandable()// Tell LinqKit to convert everything into an expression tree.
            .GroupJoin(
                inner,
                outerKeySelector,
                innerKeySelector,
                (outerItem, innerItems) => new { outerItem, innerItems })
            .SelectMany(
                joinResult => joinResult.innerItems.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (joinResult, innerItem) =>
                    resultSelector.Invoke(joinResult.outerItem, innerItem));
    }
```

The Experiment in Github updated to illustrate working solution here: [GitHub solution illustrating LeftJoin extension implemented in a .Net Standard Library](https://github.com/hewasud/Experiment_20171002)