# LINQ left self join

Tags: c#, linq

I have LINQ query as below:

```
lst_direct_managers = context.sf_guard_user_profile
 .Join(context.sf_guard_user_profile, up => up.user_id, dm => dm.direct_manager_id,
 (up, dm) => new { up, dm })
 .Where(m => m.up.is_gvo == 1)
 .Select(m => new DirectManagerModel
  {
  user_id = m.up.direct_manager_id == null ? 0 : m.up.direct_manager_id,
  dm_full_name = (m.up.first_name + " " + m.up.last_name == null ? "No Direct Manager" : m.up.first_name + " " + m.up.last_name)
  })
  .Distinct()
  .OrderBy(m => m.dm_full_name).ToList();
```

Problem is that it does not return default value in case of nulls "No Direct Manager". Can you please help me?

Comment: What you are doing is Inner join not left join.

Comment: m.up.first_name + " " + m.up.last_name: would this ever equal null?

Comment: @MatthewNorth only direct_manager_id  can be null.

Comment: @ironcurtain visit [How to implement left join in JOIN Extension method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3792904/1505865)

Comment: It's this line:
dm_full_name = (m.up.first_name + " " + m.up.last_name == null ? "No Direct Manager" : m.up.first_name + " " + m.up.last_name)

I was asking about, it looks like it would throw an exception instead of returning 'No Direct Manager'

Comment: Use a navigation property in stead of a join.